# print only lines where the first column is unique

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am looking for a way to sort a list and print all lines, whose first column appears only once - i.e., match only on the first column.
For example, I have a file where the first column is a path and the second column contains a 'type'

```
/path/foo/1 footsy
/path/foo/1 barsy
/path/foo/X barsy
/path/bar/2 footsy
/path/bar/2 barsy
/path/foo/Y footsy
```

(the file is actually sorted -k1,1)

Now, I would like to extract only cases like

```
/path/foo/X barsy
/path/foo/Y footsy
```

I am thinking about some way with awk, where I would have to store the previous line and compare the first field of the previous line to the corresponding field in the current line. But I have not yet an idea how to get it done :(
I tried to adapt a solution found in another question but it is not really working as hoped

```
awk '{
  prev=$0; path=$1; type=$2
  getline
  if ($1 != $path) {
    print prev
  }
}'
```

Comment: `foo/1` is unique from `foo/X` and `foo/Y` same as `bar/2` so result should contain 4 lines

Comment: Try `sort -u -k 1,1`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you mean that you want the path _minus the file name_? Which of the `footsy` files in `/path/foo` should be kept? The first? The last? Any? What operating system are you using? Do you have access to GNU tools?

Comment: Thomas: You say, “the file is actually sorted -k1,1”, but the data you present isn’t sorted.

Comment: This is hilarious (and I mean that ironically).  We insist that question-askers present the code that they’re using, and then, when one does, we bombard him with answers that don’t correct or build upon his attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `awk` normally reads each line of the input and invokes the script on it. 
   The cases where you would use `getline` are few and far between. 
   When your script is run with six lines of input,
   this is an overview of what happens:

   > Read line 1 normally
   >
   > > Set variables
   > >     Call `getline`, which reads line 2
   > >     Compare variables
   >
   > Read line 3 normally
   >
   > > Set variables
   > >     Call `getline`, which reads line 4
   > >     Compare variables
   >
   > Read line 5 normally
   >
   > > Set variables
   > >     Call `getline`, which reads line 6
   > >     Compare variables

   Obviously this isn’t going to work.
2. Secondly, you made a common mistake in your `awk` code.  In `awk`,
   fields from the input are referenced as `$number`
   and variables are referenced as *`variable_name`*. 
   This is different from shell scripts,
   where command line arguments are referenced as `$number`
   and variables are referenced as `$variable_name`. 
   Your test

   ```
   if ($1 != $path)
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if ($1 != path)
   ```
3. Your overall approach is flawed. 
   You can’t identify strings that occur only once in the file
   by looking at two lines at a time. 
   I believe that you can do it by looking at three lines at a time
   (i.e., by keeping the *two* previous lines in variables),
   but things like that get complicated and messy. 
   It’s probably simpler to count occurrences. 
   Here’s a minimal modification on your script to do that.

   ```
   awk '{
     if ($1 != path) {
       if (count == 1) {
         print prev
       }
       count=1
     }
     else count++
     prev=$0; path=$1
   }
   END {
       if (count == 1) {
         print prev
       }
   }'
   ```

   I deleted `type`, since you never used it.

   Disclosure: This is essentially the same as the last part of glenn’s answer.

Comment: yes, you are right - while sleeping over it I also noticed that I need a window with essential three lines for a proper comparison, i.e., keeping the two previous lines in addition to the current one

Comment: actually, I was thinking now about comm to handle it, but I really like your approach to use an occurence counter to store the info about common lines!

Answer (score 2):

These answers don't require the input to be sorted:

Store the count and last-line-seen in arrays. Requires a lot of memory for large files, and requires GNU awk

```
gawk '
    {count[$1]++; line[$1]=$0} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_str_asc"
        for (key in line) if (count[key] == 1) print line[key]
    }
' file
```

Scan the file twice, first to get the count, next to print the lines with count 1

```
awk 'NR == FNR {count[$1]++; next} count[$1]==1' file file
```

This will be the fastest and require the least memory, taking advantage of the sorted input:

```
awk '
    prev_key && prev_key != $1 {if (count==1) print prev_line; count=0}
    {prev_key=$1; prev_line=$0; count++}
    END {if (count==1) print prev_line}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell support [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), and `X` and `Y` doesn't contain spaces, tabs:

```
$ grep -Ff <(awk '{print $1" "}' <file | LC_ALL=C uniq -u) <file
/path/foo/X barsy
/path/foo/Y footsy
```

Comment: If there are 2 or more lines with `/path/foo/XX`, grep will pick them up too. You probably need `grep -f <(awk '{print "^" $1 "[[:blank:]]"} ...`

Comment: @glennjackman: Well, good point. But don't use `-F` also break if `X` contain meta characters.

Comment: seems that grep isn't a good fit for this question.

Comment: @glennjackman: Append a space to the end of 1st field can prevent `X` and `XX` case.

Comment: still doesn't anchor it to the start of the line, but that does not appear to be a problem given the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this:

```
cat text.tx | sort | uniq -c -w11 | fgrep '1 /' | awk '{print $2" "$3}'
```

with your text.txt like this

```
]#cat text.txt
/path/foo/1 footsy
/path/foo/1 barsy
/path/foo/X barsy
/path/bar/2 footsy
/path/bar/2 barsy
/path/foo/Y footsy
```

Comment: (1) `printf "%s\n" "/path/foo/X barsy" "/path/foo/Y footsy"` will also produce the requested output.  But that would be stupid; that just produces the correct result *for the **example** input*, not the problem in general.  By the same token, your answer is inappropriately tailored to the example input; it assumes that the data in the first column always begins with `/` and is 11 characters long, and that there are only two columns — none of which was specified in the problem description.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Even making those assumptions, your answer reports any path that appears once — or 11 times, or 21, 31, 451, 2001, etc.  (3) Overall, this is unnecessarily complicated.  For starters, read about [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).  But also, you’re missing the point of `uniq` — keeping the assumption about the field length, you can simplify the command to `sort text.tx | uniq -u -w11`.